# Is having an origin HTTP header bad practice when performing server-to-server HTTP requests?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, http, security, next.js

Considering this TypeScript code being executed on a "server only" module (it is **never** executed in a browser)

```
const studyResponse = await fetch(endPointUrl, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    origin
  }
}).then(res => {
  return res.json() as Promise<Study>;
});
```

Is this considered bad practice, or violating standards? Is there something in the documentation that would discourage doing this?